# The list of input methods in ibus preference is not as exhaustive as in Gnome Settings > Region & Language

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus

I recently switched to i3wm, so I have to select input methods using **IBus Preferences**. However, the input method that I used in Gnome isn't in the IBus Preferences list.

How do I add the rest of the input methods to IBus preferences? I'm using 20.04 btw.

Comparison between the two (left is **Ibus preferences**, right is **gnome settings**):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's per (IBus) design. IBus only provides a small selection of the available XKB layouts.

You can edit the `/usr/share/ibus/component/simple.xml` file yourself. (But save a copy somewhere, since your edits will be overwritten when the ibus package is updated.)

The short IBus list has been questioned in an [upstream issue](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2153).

Comment: Where do I find the info of the layout that I needed, in order to edit simple.xml?

Comment: @DucPham: You should be able to figure it out by looking at the existing items in `simple.xml`. If there is a specific layout you want to add, and fail to do so, please edit your question to be more specific and show what you tried. Then someone may be able to give you a hand.